# Laravel 4: trying to get property of non object

Tags: php, model, laravel, laravel-4, relational-database

always when I try fetch a model and it does not have a related model. e.g.

```
$jobApplication->job->title
```

i get the following error:

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

i do not want to have to wrap all calls to related models in if statments like this:

```
if( $jobApplication->job ) {

    echo $jobApplication->job->title;
}
```

Comment: Well your pretty stuck for alternatives, the other option is just disabling error reporting altogether, unless you want your code full of `@` suppressions.

Comment: Surely there is a "Laravel way" to fetch models that only contain related models...? otherwise if you are accessing something deep in a chained command its just impractical.

`$jobApplication->job->author->address->street;`

Comment: Do you want to the query to return only the ones with the related model? if so, have you checked out this: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#query-scopes ?

If you want the model to return something else when its null, then checkout the accessors: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators